# Is PostgreSQL IN() statement still fast with up to 1000 arguments?

Tags: postgresql

I'm querying to return all rows from a table except those that are in some list of values that is constant at query time.  E.g. SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (%), and % is guaranteed to be a list of values, not be a subquery.  However, this list of values may be up to 1000 elements long in some cases.  Should I limit this to a smaller sublist (as few as 50-100 elements is as low as I can go, in this case) or will there be a negligible performance gain?

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume it's a large table, otherwise it wouldn't matter much.

Depending on table size and number of keys, this may turn into a sequence scan. If there are many `IN` keys, Postgres often chooses not to use an index for it. **The more keys, the bigger the chance of a sequence scan**.

**If you use another indexed column** in `WHERE`, like:

```
select * from table where id in (%) and my_date > '2010-01-01';
```

**It's likely to fetch all rows matching the indexed** (`my_date`) **columns**, and then perform an in-memory scan on them.

**Using a `JOIN` to a persistent or temporary table may, but does not have to help**. It still will need to locate all the rows, either with a nested loop (unlikely for large data), or for a hash/merge join.

I would say the solution is:

- Use as few `IN` keys as possible.
- Use other criteria for indexing and querying whenever possible. If `IN` requires an in-memory scan of all rows, at least there will be fewer of them thanks to additional criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Use a temporary table to JOIN, gives better performance and has no limits. An IN() having a 1000 arguments, will give you problems in any database.